# VS 2017 C# MVC - Cant see NPM built bundle.js (cant publish to web either)

Tags: c#, reactjs, visual-studio-2017

I've built a C# MVC web app (not CORE) and i integrated react into it. I have npm run build on first app build.

Debugging locally everything seems fine (got task runner for watch too), but theres a bit of a problem while trying to deploy/publish to azure.

My build folder (inside Visual Studio 2017) shows as empty even tho on every build there's a "bundle.js" in there (checked with windows explorer, it is there). This problem stops VS 2017 from publishing the react part of my app.

Any idea how i could make VS show that file and publish it to azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Dragging and dropping the bundle.js into the folder made it work.

However...it seems that we cant use the BundleConfig if JS files come from NPM build so the only option is to use `@Url.Content()`